# Airflow - Run backfill command month by month

Tags: python, airflow

I've read the Airflow documatation and I realized the backfill command will run my dags for each day of the date range that I provided. But is there a way to run my dags once per month using backfill? E.g. I provide the range 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-01 and I need to run once on January, once on February, and so.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backfill will rerun failed previous runs of a specified dag given its dag_id.
It will not run for each day unless your dag identified by dag_id is run each day.
If the dag identified by dag_id is run once eevry month, backfill will follow that frequency.

A dag can easily be scheduled to run every day using a cron.